# Neutral wire becomes hot

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a pole lamp fixture in my front yard. The voltage seems to be fine (122 at the house, 114 at the lamp. When I test the wires at the lamp (when not connected to the fixture) the black is hot and the white is 0 volts (no voltage).  But when I wire the fixture up (black to black, white to white) both the black and white wires become hot. The white should remain near 0 volts, correct? I’ve tried it with two different fixtures which are both new so I know it’s not that. Any help what may be causing this?

Comment: Where do you test the voltage ? Do you test with the switch in the On or Off position ?

Comment: dropping 8v for a lamp doesn't seem "fine" to me, that's a lot of heat going somewhere. I assume those readings are with the lamp on. If not, that wire is barely connected. This is further evidenced by the fact that neutral is reverse-sagging. Sounds like the wiring out to the post is flaky.

Comment: I did an edit to (I think) correct some language you used that was incorrect (end of sentences 2 and end of first question).  The white wire is just "the white wire" and isn't necessarily neutral, ha ha, boy do we see that a lot!  Neutral is not a word to describe a wire with 0 measured voltage.  Anyway I might have been wrong, please [edit] again if what I wrote doesn't correspond to your observations.

Comment: the white is not neutral, it is switched Hot

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for a bad connection somewhere along the cable run.  In particular, it sounds like the neutral has failed.  With no load on it, it sort-of works.  With a load on, it fails entirely.